# Snowflake task gives me no error but table is empty

Tags: sql, task, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have the following TASK in Snowflake:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TASK TSK_MASTER
    WAREHOUSE = MYWH
    SCHEDULE = '1 MINUTE'
WHEN
  SYSTEM$STREAM_HAS_DATA('MYSTREAM')
AS
    INSERT INTO USER_DATA(ID,CREATED_AT,DEACTIVATED,EMAIL_ADDRESS,NAME,ROLE)
    SELECT
      vm.VALUE:id::string AS "ID",
      vm.VALUE:created_at::timestamp AS "CREATED_AT",
      vm.VALUE['profile']:deactivated::boolean AS "DEACTIVATED",
      vm.VALUE['profile']:email_address::string AS "EMAIL_ADDRESS",
      vm.VALUE['profile']:name::string AS "NAME",
      vm.VALUE:role::string AS "ROLE"
    FROM
        MYSTREAM
        , lateral flatten(input => RAW_JSON) vm
    WHERE
        vm.VALUE:entity_type::string = 'member'
        AND
        METADATA$ACTION = 'INSERT';
```

`SELECT SYSTEM$STREAM_HAS_DATA('MYSTREAM')` is `TRUE` but my task doesn't seem to run.

I then troubleshoot the following and get the IDs as intended.

```
SELECT
      vm.VALUE:id::string AS "ID"
FROM
    MYSTREAM
    , lateral flatten(input => RAW_JSON) vm
WHERE
    vm.VALUE:entity_type::string = 'member'
    AND
    SYSTEM$STREAM_HAS_DATA('MYSTREAM')
    AND
    METADATA$ACTION = 'INSERT';
```

Comment: When you run `show tasks` does the task show started?

Comment: To @GregPavlik 's point, you need to run an `ALTER TASK TSK_MASTER RESUME` statement after you create it in order for it to be active and scheduled.

Comment: thank you both. I assumed by default it runs but that makes sense to have to manually activate it at first.

Answer (score 1):

All you need to do is `ALTER TASK <TASK_NAME> RESUME`